# what is vs 2013 default c# version?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I need to know what is the **visual studio 2013** default **c#** **version** ?
please answer with correct reference and related link.

Comment: It's valid question. I just needed to know exactly the same. Most search results are questions related to support of C# 6.0 in VS 2013. Really sad to see clear question closed as unclear.

Comment: It's a valid question. The default VS2013 installation supports C# 5.0.

If one, for example, had samples or sources in c# 6.0 (with 6.0 language sintax like: articles?[0].author?.name) it would be uncompilable in his VS2013.

--
Thanks to @Dasanko for the REF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna read this article.

> This article introduces new and enhanced features in Visual Studio 2013, including Update 2.

Here is the source: [What's New in Visual Studio 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx)

Also you should know you can change the target of Visual Studio .NET Framework version. Read here: [How to: Target a Version of the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your project's target framework... for Visual Studio 2013, you can go as far up as C# 5.0/.NET 4.5.x

You can read a bit more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Versions).

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there is such concept of default .NET Framework in Visual Studio. It will install .net framework 4.5 (and 4.5.1 depending on install) and that will be selected on New Project dialog on the top. 
If you change the framework from 4.5 to 4.0 or 4.5.1, Visual Studio will remember the option and your last selected framework will be selected by default next time New Project window will pop up.

Comment: The question is about the language version and not .net framework. They are different things. You can have the latest version of C# (v 8) to compile to .net4 if you want